# Trying to make an availability table with multiple inputs in a column

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql, jinja2

I want to create a table where users register their available hours, but when I click on two or more boxes in the same column the data is overwritten by the latest time. I want to store the values in the database as a list of strings. Is my approach totally wrong? because I believe this is the best and easiest way to do what I want to do.
[image]

**views.py**

```
def availability(request):
    start = datetime(year=1, month=1, day=1, hour=8, minute=00, second=00)
    time_slots = []
    for x in range (0, 29):
        time_slots.append(str(start.strftime('%-I:%M %p')))
        start += timedelta(minutes = 30)
        x += 1

    if request.method == 'POST':
        sunday = request.POST['sunday'+str(x)]
        monday = request.POST['monday']
        tuesday = request.POST['tuesday']
        wednesday = request.POST['wednesday']
        thursday =  request.POST['thursday']
        friday = request.POST['friday']
        saturday = request.POST['saturday']


    context = {
        'if_tutor': UsersUpdated.objects.get(user_id=request.user.pk),
        'time_slots': time_slots,
    }
    return render(request, 'user/tutor_availability.html', context)
```

**HTML**

```
{% extends "user/base.html" %}
{% csrf_token %}
{% block title %}Dashboard{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content">
    <div class="inner_content">
        <h2 class="title">Availability</h2>
        <div class="top_line"></div>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Sunday</th>
                    <th>Monday</th>
                    <th>Tuesday</th>
                    <th>Wednesday</th>
                    <th>Thursday</th>
                    <th>Friday</th>
                    <th>Saturday</th>
                </tr>
                {% for time_slot in time_slots %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ time_slot }}</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{ time_slot }}" name="sunday"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{ time_slot }}" name="monday"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{ time_slot }}" name="tuesday"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{ time_slot }}" name="wednesday"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{ time_slot }}" name="thursday"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{ time_slot }}" name="friday"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{ time_slot }}" name="saturday"></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% positive on this but I believe your problem is that each  element in each column of your  rows has the same `name` value. You will need a unique `name` for each  element and request each value uniquely based on those unique names.

Comment: That could work, but that would mean I will need to make a post request in my views.py for each field (~200) because the post request cannot have more than 1 value

Comment: That's ok. This kind of implementation shouldn't affect anything performance-wise since all the data would be captured in a single post. It's just a matter of writing some clean code that captures all of the unique name keys in a for loop so you don't have to write all the `name` values out.